# MongoDB equivalent for select "of" select?

Tags: mongodb-query

I would like to know what is the best way to translate a SQL query like:

```
select * from table where id in(
Select id from table where field1="titi" )
```

For the moment I get a two steps query:

```
CALLMATCH = db.appels.find({"EVENTDATA":  /.*442251434*./} , {CALLID: 1});

db.appels.find({"CALLID": {$in: CALLMATCH} } );
```

Is there a better way to perform this kind of query?

And a second question is how to display the result in a file? (since it is not very pratical to check the result through the cmd console...)

In advance thank you for your feedback!

Regards,

Fabien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo does not support joins so you have to do two queries.

In order to save the result set to a file you can simply redirect the output to a file such as this:

```
mongo [script] > output_file.txt
```

where script is a file with your queries ending with .js